# Using Presto HLL to count rolling wau, mau

Tags: presto

I am using Presto SQL, Hyperloglog to calculate dau, wau, and mau. Tho I am getting exact same number for all of them. Anyone can suggest what's wrong with my query?

```sql
With dau_hll AS (
 SELECT
      dt,
      platform,
      service,
      account,
      country,
      CAST(APPROX_SET(userid) AS VARBINARY) AS job_hll_sketch
  FROM
      xx
      
   GROUP BY
      1,2,3,4,5
)
SELECT dt, platform, service, country,
CARDINALITY(CAST(job_hll_sketch AS HYPERLOGLOG)) AS dau,
cardinality(merge(CAST(job_hll_sketch AS HYPERLOGLOG)) OVER (PARTITION BY dt,platform,service,account,country ORDER BY dt ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)) AS wau,
cardinality(merge(CAST(job_hll_sketch AS HYPERLOGLOG)) OVER (PARTITION BY dt,platform,service,account,country ORDER BY dt ROWS BETWEEN 29 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)) AS mau            
from dau_hll
```

Comment: Did you find an explanation or solution?